# How the componentWillReceiveProps update the props in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Below is some code snippets for the componentWillReceiveProps.

Here bulkUploadRptSuccess, bulkUploadRptError are the array and bulkUploadRptException is the string.

so once state updating two array and one string it is opening the popup.
its working as expected.

But now when clicking on any thing into the application open the pop up everytime.

How can I compare the conditional array check inside the componentWillReceiveProps.

How can I compare the two array value with the equal or not inside this function 
Thanks,

```
    componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {

        let { OCFCheckConfig } = this.props;
        let { bulkUploadRptSuccess, bulkUploadRptError, bulkUploadRptException } = OCFCheckConfig;

        if (nextProps.OCFCheckConfig.bulkUploadRptSuccess.length > 0 || nextProps.OCFCheckConfig.bulkUploadRptError.length > 0) {

          this.addPopupOpen();
        }


       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentWillReceiveProps` doesn't update props. It actually receives updated props when parent re-render or you're connected to redux and your store gets updated. Anyways It is unsafe to use ComponentWillReceiveProps. Now here we have a replacement for it, `getDerivedStateFromProps`.